# accelerometer for linear displacement

Tags: accelerometer

I have accelerometer readings from the **android device.**
I would like to know what kind of acceleration this data represents(rotation or linear acceleration).

Is there anyway I can use this data to distinguish between rotation and translation(if it has both)?

I tried low-pass-filtering the data and find the distance using this code:

```
        oldaccel+=0.1428* (accel-oldaccel); //low pass filtering
        S+=((V*dT)+ (0.5*oldaccel*dT*dT)); //finding the distance with previous velocity
        V+=(oldaccel*dT);                  //updating the velocity
```

(  oldaccel-filtered data
  accel-accelerometer data
  S-distance,V-velocity,dT-sampling period)

It doesn't give me the distance expected for a linear motion(I'm guessing useful data is being eliminated along with noise?)

Comment: the accelerometer readings is obtained by choosing TYPE_ ACCELERATION in sensor service.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to highpass filter to yield translational acceleration,depending on the nature of the translations you're talking about. This doesn't take into account any processing the Android already does.

Comment: Translation in my case would be slow motion say to the left or right. But how does the nature of translation matter?

Comment: And I will try a high pass filter. What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Gravity is an acceleration, according to Einstein.  You need to remove any offsets due to gravity.  If not for this, you wouldn't need to filter at all, as your integration is effectively a low pass filter.

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense. And works out theoretically. But when I implement this in code, I just can't find the displacement. The variable S quickly accumulates to a large value.

Comment: This is simply not practical without sensors that are orders of magnitude better.

Comment: Saturation displacement is very common when double integrating from accelerometers.  Got to start with the baby steps.  When the thing isn't moving, are you still saturating?  Are you reading a signed number from the accelerometer?  Are you putting the results of your high-pass filter into a signed number?  Is your high-pass filter good enough to do what it needs to do?  It needs a real low cutoff frequency.